# How to add/enable "php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll" on cPanel?

Tags: php, cpanel, sqlsrv

I am currently working on a PHP CodeIgniter project that fetches data on MSSQL Server. I have extracted "php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll" on "C:\xampp\php\ext" and added some configurations on "php.ini" with "extension = php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll".

My code works perfect on local until I uploaded it on cPanel. 
It gives me error "Message: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()."

I've seen solutions about PEAR packages, ini_set() function and stuff but I still cannot find a way to include/enable/use "php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll".

Can anyone please help me solve this? I badly need your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "uploaded it on cPanel"? You mean SQLSRV drivers are not installed on your production server? Need to know more about that environment? Is it shared hosting? What is it? Did you setup PHP there?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, i mean SQLSRV drivers are not installed on production server. It is VPS actually.

Comment: So, some information that would help us help you would be for example the operating system of the server you are trying to install the drivers on. Where did the current PHP install come from? Having PHP 7.2 suggests you are using a custom repository like IUS or remi.